# Bing Maps not loading tiles from local app data

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I need to load custom map tiles into my *UWP Bing Maps* app, and I need to load them from `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`.

What happens is that tiles are not loaded and the map is completely black.

While doing some troubleshooting I noticed that tiles from app package were loaded fine, and the issue was related to `LocalFolder` and `LocalCacheFoler` only.

So what I did was to copy the same image from app package to local folder (I'm copying to the correct one, even tested with images generated at runtime and stored in `LocalFolder`) and use this code as tile source:

```
var localTileSource = new LocalMapTileDataSource();
localTileSource.UriRequested += async (s, e) =>
{
    var deferral = e.Request.GetDeferral();                                                           
    e.Request.Uri = (new Random().NextDouble() < 0.5) ? new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/background.png") : new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/background.png");
    deferral.Complete();
};
```

and this is what happens:

[image]

As you can see, local tiles are not loaded and thy're plain black while the very same file inside app package is loaded correctly.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your feedback. It seems there is some problem when providing a custom source that points to app's local storage for [**LocalMapTileDataSource**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.localmaptiledatasource.aspx). We've reported this issue internally and I will update my answer once there is any progress.

Besides, `LocalMapTileDataSource` can load tiles from local storage. We can specify the Uri in the constructor of `LocalMapTileDataSource` like following:

```cs
LocalMapTileDataSource localTileSource = new LocalMapTileDataSource("ms-appdata:///local/background.png");
```

Or set the **[UriFormatString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.localmaptiledatasource.uriformatstring.aspx)** like:

```cs
LocalMapTileDataSource localTileSource = new LocalMapTileDataSource();
localTileSource.UriFormatString = "ms-appdata:///local/background.png";
```

In these ways, you should be able to load tiles from local app data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to set `UriFormatString`, the code in the OP was just an example. The real case scenario was related to building a custom tile renderer, so I'm generating tiles in the `UriRequested` handler and I'm saving them in cache to re-use them later. If I save them to `LocalData` everything's fine, but they shouldn't be added to OneDrive backup and that's why I needed to save them into `LocalCache`.

Comment: @StepTNT Thank you for your feedback, we have logged this issue internally and the related team is investigating it.

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Was this issue ever fixed?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, why don't you try using a CustoMapTileSource? Instead of writing tiles to the cache folder and supplying the URI to a LocalMapTileDataSource, you can just supply the bitmap directly.